# Why appsync adds x-amz-cf-id as a response header

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, aws-appsync

from the docs [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/RequestAndResponseBehaviorCustomOrigin.html),

> CloudFront adds the header to the viewer request before forwarding the request to your origin. The header value contains an encrypted string that uniquely identifies the request.

Now, when inspecting my appsync response on the client (postman), I find `x-amz-cf-id` as a response header. But I am sure my system has nothing to do with CloudFront,

My questions,

1. Does appsync uses cloudfront, (by default somewhere internally) ?
2. In what scenario(s) is this header added to my appsync response ?
3. What does it tells me(client) with respect to appsync (other than the cloudfront-req-id ofcourse) ?

Comment: Does that not answer your query ?

Comment: for the most part it does, thanks :) Sorry I was bit lazy to completely understand what you answered ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

appsync, api gateway, cognito and other lots of services use cloudFront in the backend/internally by AWS for high performance and to reduce latency etc purposes. CloudFront is playing just a role of reverse proxy , nothing else.

Because CloudFront always serves x-amz-cf-id header in response which can be used to track individual request(the string is unique), There is no use of this for appsync other then if AWS asks you provide his to track some failed requests if you contact them.

When you resolve the appsync endpoint and perform a reverse dns on that IP address, you'll see it actually use cloudfront.